# Printing Produces Error "Could not find image named 'LayoutDirection1.png'."

Tags: java, macos, printing

I recently tried running the [HelloWorldPrinter.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/examples/HelloWorldPrinter.java) file that is included as part of Oracle's [A Basic Printing Program](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html) tutorial. The code does what it is supposed to, but right before the print dialog box appears, I get the following output in my console, which appears in red letters:

```
2013-04-01 21:06:09.512 java[16458:407] Could not find image named 'LayoutDirection1.png'.
```

Obviously a problem has been reported, but I don't see anything wrong with the print dialog box. I'm not sure what this means and if it is something that I should fix. When I export HelloWorldPrinter into an app, this error still appears (via Console.app), so it's not a problem with Eclipse. If it matters, I'm currently using Mac OS 10.7.5.

EDIT: Also tried removing the line about setting the look and feel and also setting to default Mac OS X look and feel, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Could it be another project in your workspace giving the error?
Does the program run or break?

Comment: The program runs despite the error. And I've never encountered this error before in anything else I've done in the workspace.

Comment: I don't like giving up without knowing the problem, but I would chalk it up somehow to a difference in OS since it's obviously a picture that Eclipse is using, if your prgm isn't using it.

Comment: I exported HelloWorldPrinter into a standalone app to test if Eclipse was indeed the issue. Console.app shows the same error message right before the print dialog box appears in the app, so it's not Eclipse.

Comment: If you imported the file, try creating a new project and copy and pasting the code into a new .java file.

Comment: The file was not imported; it was done just as you say.

Comment: That's all I got, the only other errors I found like this were on OpenOffice and Thunderbird, the only slightly common denom was the fact they are all printing somehow.

Comment: Perhaps someone could see if this error happens when running on a platform other than Mac OS X?

Comment: I see the same message when printing in a non-Java (C++, Objective-C) app built with Xcode, in OS X 10.7.5.  My guess is that it's a bug in the OS X printing code.